# Retrieving Dynamic SOQL results. Runtime error - "Invalid field Owner.Name for..."

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, dynamic-soql

I had a question in regards to dynamically retrieving the results of Dynamic SOQL that I have set up in my controller. I want to be able to access fields on the Lead object (Lead.Name) itself as well as relationships (Lead.Owner.Name).

The dynamic soql works great, but I'm having problems when I try to read in the values of the result. Is there any way I can pull in values for fields on the sObject itself as well as values from a relationship? Here's a snippet of the problematic code:

```
Lead lead = [SELECT Id, OwnerID, Owner.Name, Name from Lead where Id = '00QP0000003r4f8']; //*Note in the actual code I'm using a String and Database.query()
String apiname = 'owner.name';
String apiname2 = 'Name';

//this works, but we don't want to hardcode the value
system.debug('lead owner.name ='+lead.owner.name);

String result1 = String.ValueOf(lead.get(apiname2));
System.Debug(result1);
//returns name of the lead record just fine

String result2 = String.ValueOf(lead.get(apiname));
//ERROR on runtime - System.SObjectException: Invalid field owner.name for Lead

System.Debug(result2);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, both answers solved my problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Doug B's answer, I wrote a utility method to do this:

```
public static Object getSobjectField(Sobject sObj, String fieldRef) {

        Sobject sObjNode    = sObj;
        //  fieldRef is relative to the sobject and may include relationshipNames
        //      Handle use cases:
        //          fld0                - fld0 on Sobject passed as argument
        //          fld0.fld1           - fld1 is on sobject fld0
        //          fld0.fld1. ... fldN - fldN is on sobject fldN-1
        String[] fieldList  = fieldRef.split('\\.');

        for (Integer i=0; i < fieldList.size() -1; i++) {
            sObjNode    = (Sobject) sObjNode.getSobject(fieldList[i]);  // intermediate fields are sobjects
            if (sObjNode == null) return null;
        }
        return sObjNode.get(fieldList[fieldList.size()-1]); // use fldN
    }
```

Example:  `String ownerName = (String) Util.getSobjectField(lead,'owner.name');`

Answer (score 4):

You can't reference a relationship in dynamic SOQL they way you are attempting ie `lead.get('Owner.Name')`.

You will need to first get your User (Owner) record, and then get the Name.

```
sObject owner = lead.getSObject('Owner');

owner.get('Name');
```

You can determine the sObject Type by checking the OwnerId.

```
Id theId = l.OwnerId; 
System.debug( theId.getSObjectType() );
```

Link to the Documentation for the [ID Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_Id_getSObjectType)

Comment: What if you don't know what SObject the relationship will be? Can you retrieve that and build out the getSObject() method on the fly somehow? The goal is to make this truly dynamic...

Comment: You can determine the sObject Type by checking the OwnerId.  `Id theId = l.OwnerId;
System.debug( theId.getSObjectType() );`